# return JSON API as individual items, then sort with PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I have an JSON API that returns data about beverages in a tap house. I have it coded so that if the $days_on returns a value of 1 or less, it displays that beverage. Think of this as like a "recently tapped" section of the website. Now what I want to do, is if no beverages are being shown in this section because nothing has been tapped in the last 24 hours, I want to display a message that says "Sorry nothing has been recently tapped in the last 24 hours".

The code I have here is completely ignoring my comparison operator and is always showing the "sorry..." message even when beverages have been tapped in the last 24 hours.

```
<? php
$string = $string = file_get_contents("https://service.digitalpour.com/BeerDashboard/api/v2/MenuItems/5398d80cfb890c0b0cf8baab/1/Tap?apiKey=5398db2afb890c0c88089fe7");
$json_taps = json_decode($string, true);
$t = 1;
foreach($json_taps as $beverage) {
    $item_name = $beverage['MenuItemDisplayDetail']['DisplayName'];
    $producer_name = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['FullProducerList'];
    $beverage_name = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['BeverageNameWithVintage'];
    $beverage_color = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['StyleColor'];
    $year = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Year'];
    $beverage_abv = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Abv'];
    $beverage_ibu = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Ibu'];
    $beverage_type = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['BeverageType'];
    $b_display_order = $beverage['DisplayOrder'];
    $producer_location = "";
    $producer_url = "";
    switch ($beverage_type) {
        case "Beer":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Brewery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Brewery']['BreweryUrl'];
            $beverage_style = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['BeerStyle']['CultureAwareStyleName'];
            break;
        case "Cider":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Cidery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Cidery']['CideryUrl'];
            $beverage_style = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['CiderStyle']['CultureAwareStyleName'];
            break;
        case "Mead":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Meadery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Meadery']['MeaderyUrl'];
            $beverage_style = "Mead";
            break;
        case "Wine":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Winery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Winery']['WineryUrl'];
            $beverage_style = "Wine";
            break;
        case "Kombucha":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['KombuchaMaker']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['KombuchaMaker']['Url'];
            $beverage_style = "Kombucha";
            break;
        case "Soft Drink":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkMaker']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkMaker']['Url'];
            $beverage_style = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkStyle']['StyleName'];
            break;
    }
    $date_put_on = $beverage['DatePutOn'];
    $bottle_size = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['Size'];
    $bottle_price = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['Price'];
    $beverage_ps = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['DisplayName'];
    $in_bottles = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['AvailableInBottles'];
    $keg_size = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['KegSize'];
    $oz_remaining = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['EstimatedOzLeft'];
    $days_on = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['DaysOn'];
    $time_on = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['TimeOn'];
    $logo = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['BeverageProducer']['LogoImageUrl'];
    $growl_logo = "/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/tap-list-logo.png";
    $sorry = '<h3>Sorry, nothing new has been tapped in the last 24 hours.<br><a href="/whats-on-tap">Check out our taplist!</a></h3>';
    $scale = 1.0; //
    //get listing logo
    if (empty($logo)) {
        $listing_logo = $growl_logo;
    }
    else {
        $listing_logo = $logo;
    }
    //calculating percentage of keg remaining
    // Get Percentage out of 100
    if (!empty($keg_size)) {
        $percent = $oz_remaining / $keg_size;
    }
    else {
        $percent = 0;
    }
    // Limit to 100 percent (if more than the max is allowed)
    if ($percent > 1) {
        $percent = 1;
    }
    if ($percent < 0) {
        $percent = .005;
    }
    $percent_remaining = number_format($percent * 100, 0);
    if ($percent_remaining < 1) {
        $percent_remaining = "< 1";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining == "100") {
        $color = "#00ff00";
        $status = "full";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining > 75) {
        $color = "#00ff00";
        $status = "mostly";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining > 50) {
        $color = "#ffff00";
        $status = "half";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining > 25) {
        $color = "#ffaa00";
        $status = "close";
    }
    else {
        $color = "#ff0000";
        $status = "dry";
    }
    $html = '<div class="spb_content_element col-sm-6 column_container listing">'.
    '<div class="spb_wrapper">'.
    '<div class="container"><div class="row">'.
    '<div class="spb_content_element spb_single_image noframe col-xs-4 growl-pic-element mb0">'.
    '<div class="spb_wrapper"><figure class="animated-overlay overlay-alt clearfix">'.
    '<img width="100" height="225" alt="growler-small" class="attachment-full growl-pic" src="'.$listing_logo.
    '"></figure>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="spb_content_element col-xs-8">'.
    '<div class="spb_wrapper">'.
    '<table class="featured-growls">'.
    '<tbody>'.
    '<tr class="title">'.
    '<td class="title">'.$beverage_name.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="author">'.
    '<td class="by">BY</td><td class="author">'.$producer_name.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="from">'.
    '<td class="from">'.$producer_location.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="details">'.
    '<td class="price">percent remaining</td><td class="price_val" style="color:'.$color.
    '">'.$percent_remaining.
    '%</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="details_two">'.
    '<td class="type">TYPE</td><td class="type_val">'.$beverage_style.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="details_two">'.
    '<td class="abv">ABV</td><td class="abv_val">'.$beverage_abv.
    '%</td>'.
    '<td class="ibus">IBU</td><td class="ibus_val">'.$beverage_ibu.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '</tbody>'.
    '</table>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    ($t == $countnumrows ? '' : '');
    if ($days_on <= 1) {
        echo $html;
    }
    else {
        echo $sorry;
        break;
    }
}; ?>
```

this is the code that seems to work. do you see any problems with the way i have this?

```
<?php
$has_tap = false;
$sorry = '<h3>Sorry, nothing new has been tapped in the last 24 hours.<br><a href="/whats-on-tap">Check out our taplist!</a></h3>';

//all that other stuff

($t == $countnumrows ? '' : '');


if ($days_on <= 1) {
$has_tap = true;
echo $html;
}

}

if ($has_tap == false) {
echo $sorry;
}

?>
```

Comment: There is a space between <? and php.

Comment: Should echo $sorry; happen in each loop ?

Comment: the $sorry should happen once only if $days_on <= 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what you are trying to achieve but,

I think You need to remove the `break;` else it will exit the foreach loop at some point and will not iterate through the entire array.

Try this code

```
<?php
$has_tap = false;
$sorry = '<h3>Sorry, nothing new has been tapped in the last 24 hours.<br><a href="/whats-on-tap">Check out our taplist!</a></h3>';

$string = $string = file_get_contents("https://service.digitalpour.com/BeerDashboard/api/v2/MenuItems/5398d80cfb890c0b0cf8baab/1/Tap?apiKey=5398db2afb890c0c88089fe7");
$json_taps = json_decode($string, true);
$t = 1;
foreach($json_taps as $beverage) {
    $item_name = $beverage['MenuItemDisplayDetail']['DisplayName'];
    $producer_name = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['FullProducerList'];
    $beverage_name = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['BeverageNameWithVintage'];
    $beverage_color = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['StyleColor'];
    $year = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Year'];
    $beverage_abv = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Abv'];
    $beverage_ibu = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Ibu'];
    $beverage_type = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['BeverageType'];
    $b_display_order = $beverage['DisplayOrder'];
    $producer_location = "";
    $producer_url = "";
    switch ($beverage_type) {
        case "Beer":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Brewery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Brewery']['BreweryUrl'];
            $beverage_style = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['BeerStyle']['CultureAwareStyleName'];
            break;
        case "Cider":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Cidery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Cidery']['CideryUrl'];
            $beverage_style = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['CiderStyle']['CultureAwareStyleName'];
            break;
        case "Mead":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Meadery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Meadery']['MeaderyUrl'];
            $beverage_style = "Mead";
            break;
        case "Wine":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Winery']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Winery']['WineryUrl'];
            $beverage_style = "Wine";
            break;
        case "Kombucha":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['KombuchaMaker']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['KombuchaMaker']['Url'];
            $beverage_style = "Kombucha";
            break;
        case "Soft Drink":
            $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkMaker']['Location'];
            $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkMaker']['Url'];
            $beverage_style = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkStyle']['StyleName'];
            break;
    }
    $date_put_on = $beverage['DatePutOn'];
    $bottle_size = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['Size'];
    $bottle_price = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['Price'];
    $beverage_ps = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['DisplayName'];
    $in_bottles = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['AvailableInBottles'];
    $keg_size = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['KegSize'];
    $oz_remaining = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['EstimatedOzLeft'];
    $days_on = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['DaysOn'];
    $time_on = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['TimeOn'];
    $logo = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['BeverageProducer']['LogoImageUrl'];
    $growl_logo = "/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/tap-list-logo.png";
    $scale = 1.0; //
    //get listing logo
    if (empty($logo)) {
        $listing_logo = $growl_logo;
    }
    else {
        $listing_logo = $logo;
    }
    //calculating percentage of keg remaining
    // Get Percentage out of 100
    if (!empty($keg_size)) {
        $percent = $oz_remaining / $keg_size;
    }
    else {
        $percent = 0;
    }
    // Limit to 100 percent (if more than the max is allowed)
    if ($percent > 1) {
        $percent = 1;
    }
    if ($percent < 0) {
        $percent = .005;
    }
    $percent_remaining = number_format($percent * 100, 0);
    if ($percent_remaining < 1) {
        $percent_remaining = "< 1";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining == "100") {
        $color = "#00ff00";
        $status = "full";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining > 75) {
        $color = "#00ff00";
        $status = "mostly";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining > 50) {
        $color = "#ffff00";
        $status = "half";
    }
    elseif($percent_remaining > 25) {
        $color = "#ffaa00";
        $status = "close";
    }
    else {
        $color = "#ff0000";
        $status = "dry";
    }
    $html = '<div class="spb_content_element col-sm-6 column_container listing">'.
    '<div class="spb_wrapper">'.
    '<div class="container"><div class="row">'.
    '<div class="spb_content_element spb_single_image noframe col-xs-4 growl-pic-element mb0">'.
    '<div class="spb_wrapper"><figure class="animated-overlay overlay-alt clearfix">'.
    '<img width="100" height="225" alt="growler-small" class="attachment-full growl-pic" src="'.$listing_logo.
    '"></figure>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="spb_content_element col-xs-8">'.
    '<div class="spb_wrapper">'.
    '<table class="featured-growls">'.
    '<tbody>'.
    '<tr class="title">'.
    '<td class="title">'.$beverage_name.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="author">'.
    '<td class="by">BY</td><td class="author">'.$producer_name.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="from">'.
    '<td class="from">'.$producer_location.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="details">'.
    '<td class="price">percent remaining</td><td class="price_val" style="color:'.$color.
    '">'.$percent_remaining.
    '%</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="details_two">'.
    '<td class="type">TYPE</td><td class="type_val">'.$beverage_style.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr class="details_two">'.
    '<td class="abv">ABV</td><td class="abv_val">'.$beverage_abv.
    '%</td>'.
    '<td class="ibus">IBU</td><td class="ibus_val">'.$beverage_ibu.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '</tbody>'.
    '</table>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    ($t == $countnumrows ? '' : '');
    if ($days_on <= 1) {
        $has_tap = true;
        echo $html;
    }
    else {
        echo $sorry;
        break;
    }
}

if($has_tap === false){
    echo $sorry;
}

?>
```

Comment: If I removed the break, it will just echo the "sorry..." over and over again. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Then you need to put the "sorry" out of the for loop. By breaking early you are not looping through the entire array.

Comment: So you're saying that $sorry needs to be defined outside of the php tags, which is the "loop"? I am still relatively new to php. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my original post. What you did makes sense, so I tried your code and it wasn't quite working but very close. Let me know if what my adaptaion does will cause any problems you might forsee?

Comment: If $has_tap = false; is outside the for loop then I don't see any issue with that.